# Python DP min cost path of a triangle of ints

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I am working on some code to compute the shortest path in a given 2D array that represents a triangle. This is using DP to get to the solution, it needs to output a path rather than the final cost. I understand that it is populating the array bottom-up style, but I will implement back-tracking once this outputs the correct cost.

This is the code i currently have. For some reason it is just concatenating the numbers rather than splitting it like adding a string together.

```
with open("small_triangle.txt") as textFile:
    perm = [line.split() for line in textFile]

output = [None] * len(perm)
lines = perm

for j in range(len(lines)):
    print(lines[j])
output[0] = lines[0][0]

for x in range(len(lines)-2, 0, -1):
    for y in range(0 , x):

        if(lines[x+1][y] < lines[x+1][y+1]):
            output[x] = lines[x+1][y]
            lines[x][y] += lines[x+1][y]
        else:
            output[x] = lines[x+1][y+1]
            lines[x][y] += lines[x+1][y+1]

print(output)
#for i in range(len(output)):
#   print("\n"+output[i])
```

given this 2D array

```
['79']
['82', '04']
['86', '93', '64']
['34', '30', '17', '44']
['41', '79', '83', '33', '86']
['10', '34', '55', '92', '26', '23']
['54', '84', '30', '79', '40', '30', '65']
['94', '64', '79', '36', '79', '78', '72', '36']
['12', '88', '25', '57', '72', '37', '37', '45', '26']
['92', '24', '07', '07', '04', '48', '25', '60', '54', '72']
```

This is the array it is outputting

```
['79', '8630793430365704', '17332630723725', '332630723725', '2630723725', '30723725', '723725', '3725', '54', None]
```

Comment: Your values in the 'triangle' are strings, you need to cast them all to int otherwise addition (+) will concatenate strings instead of adding integers.

Comment: when I do that, such as `int(arr elm)` I get, `cannot call this function on ints`, is there another way to do that. I am more Java proficient so this is a bit confusing thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are trying to cast to int?

Comment: within the for loop I am doing, `output[x] = int(lines[x+1][y])` just to test it and it is still outputting the same concatenated output. No error though so a little confusing

Comment: You need to cast to int before any operation, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triangle contains strings instead of integers. To fix that we will need to cast all those strings to `int` before doing any operations on them, otherwise the `+` operation will concat and the `<` comparison operator will do a dictionary comparison on strings.

```
with open("small_triangle.txt") as textFile:
    perm = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in textFile]
```

Although, your algorithm is wrong. I will not fix it all for you, but I can point out the main error. Have a look at your loop

```
for x in range(len(lines)-2, 0, -1):
    for y in range(0 , x):

        if(lines[x+1][y] < lines[x+1][y+1]):
            # On every iteration that overwrites output[x]
            output[x] = lines[x+1][y]
            lines[x][y] += lines[x+1][y]
        else:
            # On every iteration that overwrites output[x]
            output[x] = lines[x+1][y+1]
            lines[x][y] += lines[x+1][y+1]
```

Notice that for a given `x`, you change the value of `output[x]` on every iteration of `for y in range(0 , x)`. So basically what is going on is that you are not keeping track of what your best answer is, you are simply overwriting it.

What you want to do for a dynamic programming solution is to fill in, from bottom to top, what the minimal distance to the bottom and the associated path are for every element. Then you should end up with a solution at the top of your triangle.

Comment: for some reason it is still outputting as follows `[79, 321, 240, 223, 190, 164, 134, 62, 54, None]` 240,223,190 is not in the triangle, so there is still some concatenation going on

Comment: Your algorithm is not correct, I'll edit in a moment

Comment: Here, I pointed out what the main error is, but I cannot do anymore as it would require a considerable amount of work and it might be an assignment.

Comment: its a challenge on leetcode that Im working on, but thanks for your help

Comment: If it is a challenge, I wish you the best of luck. Doing it by yourself is the best way to learn from there!